# Detect if NSNumber is equal to NULL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsnumber

How do I detect if a NSNumber is NULL? For example, I use a NSLog to display the value of a NSNumber and if there is an incorrect value, such as letters, it shows "null" in the log. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good point, I'm using the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just do

```
NSNumber *testNumber;

if(testNumber == nil){

NSLog(@"the testNumber is nil");

}
```

Comment: I think that @Julian answer is better, because compiler throws no warnings. If I would compare NSNumber to nil like in an _accepted answer_, the compiler will warn me about comparison between **pointer** and **integer** ('int' and 'void *').